# Other way to rewrite/improve this query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is there other way to rewrite/improve this query, trying to make it with less typo and if possible improve performance:

```
Select 
 (Select Sum(value) from table1
  where code = 'B2' 
    and date between DATE '2017-01-01' 
                 and DATE '2017-03-31')
   +
 (Select Sum(value) from table2
  where code = 'B2' 
    and date between DATE '2017-04-01' 
                 and DATE '2017-04-30')
```

I also tried with union all but this still is not what I need:

```
Select Sum(value) 
  from (Select code, value from table1 
        Where date between DATE '2017-01-01' 
                       and DATE '2017-03-31')
  union all 
       (Select code, value from table1 
        Where date between DATE '2017-04-01'
                   and DATE '2017-04-30')
 where code = 'B2'
```

Thanks

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do not post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query is fine . . . assuming you have a `from dual` at the end.

For performance, you want indexes on `table1(code, date, value)` and `table2(code, date, value)`.  Note that the order of the columns in the indexes is important.

Answer (score 1):

If, with typo you mean that you have the criteria code = 'B2' twice in your query, you can move it to your from clause. Anyway, be aware that a subquery can return NULL. Use `NVL` (or `COALESCE`) to deal with this.

```
select 
  nvl((select sum(value) from table1 
       where code = x.code and date between date '2017-01-01' and date '2017-03-31'), 0)
   +
  nvl((select sum(value) from table2
       where code = x.code and date between date '2017-04-01' and date '2017-04-30'), 0)
from (select 'B2' as code from dual) x;
```